# Dynamically change inline css by calling a php function

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to call a php function inside the inline style of an element. The function is suppposed to return a string with the color red but im getting a **"value not allowed here"** 
 error when I try to call the `checkMark` function.

```
    foreach ($array as $value){
        echo '<p style="{checkMark($value["firstMark"])}">'.$value['firstMark'].'</p>';
    }

    function checkMark($mark){
        if($mark < 5){
            return 'color:red';
        }
    }
?>
```

I have tried to escape characters this way:

```
echo "<td style=\"{checkMark(\$value[\"firstMark\"])}\">{$value['firstMark']}</td>";
```

However its not calling the function, just printing the string the exact same string I have written.

Comment: `echo '<p style="'.checkMark($value["firstMark"]).'">'.$value['firstMark'].'</p>';`

Comment: Look at the highlighting here. `checkMark` is inside of a string. You'll have to break out of the string in order to pass the value in.

Comment: That's because the PHP interpreter is seeing everything inside the `'` quote marks as a string - i.e. a static piece of text - rather than code, because that's how it works. If you want to execute some code, put it outside the string, just like any other code.